# Protractor: Wait for angular to finish animation

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I have a slider menu on my page which appear after an interval of time through an animation. I would to know how can I handle click action without using `browser.wait(condition, timeout)` since depending on the network traffic to fetch data in a remote database.

The page rendering can take long time thus protractor is triggering timeouts error. I have been trying as bellow to use jQuery in order to wait for all transition and animation event to finish, but it is still not working.

```
BasePage.prototype.clickMenuButton = function(menuName) {

var link = element(by.linkText(menuName));

browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.executeScript("jQuery('html > *').one('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd', function(){})").then(
    function() {
        link.click();
    },
    function (error) { console.log("Error : ", error); }
);
}
```

Does anyone know a way to wait for angularjs to finish rendering and animation without using `browser.wait` and timeouts?

Comment: `browser.wait` is made for waiting, so why wouldnt you want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Protractor "incompatibility" with Angular JS. Most of the people calls this a bug, but nobody is sure about this.

However, if this issue occurs, the Angular and Protractor teams recommends in order to fix the $timeout awaits, to replace the $timeout function with a $interval function. They're almost the same, they both achieve the same thing.

**$interval function fixes the protractor $timeout issue.**

[Official documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md) states that **You should use the $interval for anything that polls continuously (introduced in Angular 1.2rc3).**

In this case, $timeout it's not a good option for Front End Developers(AngularJS developers) neither for JavaScript Automation Developers(Protractor developers).

Another option would be to either use a timeout in your test application, either turn the browser sync off.
Here's my example for ignoreSynchronization function.

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
                browser.wait(toast.isPresent(), 3000).then(
                    function(arr) {
                        if (arr) {
                            toast.getText().then(function(txt) {
                                //  console.log(txt);
                                expect(txt).toContain(caption);
                            });
                        } else {
                            toast.getText().then(function(txt) {
                                console.log('current toast: ' + txt);
                                console.log('modal not catched. see bug with $timeout \n ' +
                                    caption + " \n" +
                                    "==> Error! NOT PRESENT");
                            });

                        }

                    }
                );
                browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
```

You could also have a look over [their official github issue tracker](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/169). This page states that if you have a $timeout function, that the developer cannot change this(this seems a bit unlikely, and seems like one of the bad QA/dev relationship) you should use the ignoreSynchronization function.

The main conclusion is that, **in order to fix protractor $timeout awaits for Angular the Front End developer should easily replace $timeout with $interval**.

Let me know if it helps.